# Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, dispatcher

I bind observable dictionary from view model to view. I use Caliburn Micro Framework.

**View:**

```
    <ListBox Name="Friends" 
             SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedFriendsIndex,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFriend, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Style="{DynamicResource friendsListStyle}"
             IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="Value.Nick"
             Grid.Row="2" 
             Margin="4,4,4,4"
             PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp"
             PreviewMouseRightButtonDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown" 
             MouseRightButtonDown="ListBox_MouseRightButtonDown"
             Micro:Message.Attach="[MouseDoubleClick]=[Action OpenChatScreen()]" >
```

**Code from view model class.**

Properties look like this:

```
public MyObservableDictionary<string, UserInfo> Friends
{
    get { return _friends; }
    set
    {
        _friends = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Friends);
    }
}
```

In Dispatcher timer I call  every 3 seconds in seperate thread new service method.

So I constructor of view model I have this:

```
        _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
        _dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        _dispatcherTimer.Start();

        _threadDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
```

And Timer tick method is here:

```
    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() =>
        {
            //get new data from server
            MyObservableDictionary<string, UserInfo> freshFriends = _service.GetFriends(Account);

            _threadDispatcher.BeginInvoke((System.Action)(() =>
            {
                //clear data, Friend is property which is binded on listobox control
                Friends.Clear();

                //here is problem - > refresh data
                foreach (var freshFriend in freshFriends)
                {
                    Friends.Add(freshFriend);

                }
            }));
        }).Start();
```

when I run app I get this error:

```
Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.


   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren)
   at System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
```

I try replace dispatcher:

this        `_threadDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;`

with this:  `_threadDispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;`

But it doesn’t help. Thank for advice.

MyObservableDicionary is not dependency object or have dependecy property:

```
public class MyObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> :
    IDictionary<TKey, TValue>,
    INotifyCollectionChanged,
    INotifyPropertyChanged
{..}
```

Answer (score 34):

I encountered a similiar situation.
I bound an ObservableCollection of a class named Person to a datagrid, and Person.SkinColor is SolidColorBrush.
What I did was the following:

```cs
foreach (Person person in personData)
{
　PersonModel person= new Person( );
　......               
　personModel.SkinColor = new SolidColorBrush(person.FavoriteColor);
　personModel.SkinColor.Freeze();
　.....
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem with an ImageSource. Calling Freeze() also worked in my case

Answer (score 24):

Just a guess, but Tasks get created on a background thread, by default. Try creating your task using the Task.Factory overload with a SynchronizationContext. I'm not sure if using the Dispatcher inside a Task works the way one would expect.

```
var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiContext);
```

Once you do that, you should be able to modify your backing property without using the dispatcher.

Comment: Great answer - yes this approach does work, solved a problem I'd been hitting my head against for far too long.

Comment: But this does not execute the task in background anymore, right? it becomes an on-ui-operation.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness I'd mention that the approved answer doesn't suit if you've got some objects that doesn't inherit [Freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx) class. The standard ObservableCollection only allows updates from the dispatcher thread, so you need a thread-safe analog. There are two solutions of WPF guru [Dean Chalk](http://deanchalk.com) what solve the problem:

1. Create a thread-safe observable collection. It's an old school solution that just works. To get the source code check a [short article in his blog](http://deanchalk.com/2010/02/01/thread-safe-dispatcher-safe-observable-collection-for-wpf/).
2. Use [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) library. See [this article](http://deanchalk.com/2013/05/16/multi-threading-observablecollection-reactive-extensions/) for an example. It's a bit bulky for one task, but meanwhile it brings a bunch of modern tools which come in handy.

**UPDATE (31 July 2015):**

Links to Dean Chalk's blog are dead, so here are alternatives:

- Thread-safe observable collection: [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20101105144104/http:/www.deanchalk.me.uk/post/Thread-Safe-Dispatcher-Safe-Observable-Collection-for-WPF.aspx), [source code](https://github.com/tamirdresher/WinRTThreadSafeObservableCollection/blob/master/ThreadSafeObservableCollection.cs).
- Multi-threading, ObservableCollection, Reactive Extensions: [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20130730053625/http://deanchalk.com/2013/05/16/multi-threading-observablecollection-reactive-extensions).

Comment: your link is ded ;( Perhaps you could copy the information here instead of linking elsewhere?

Comment: @JumpingJezza, I added alternative links. Both solutions are too bulky for a post.

Comment: Not to worry. I had an Observable Collection of type ImageSource and simply freezing the ImageSource worked.

Answer (score 3):

Is your data source a DependencyObject? If so, it needs to be created on the UI thread, too. 
Usually, you shouldn't need to inherit your datasource from DependencyObject though.

Comment: What do you mean with data source ? Property Friend?

Comment: Your view model, or anything that is bound to the UI.

Comment: No, VM is create with Caliburn Micro, in this class I haven’t any dependecy properties and objects.

Comment: Maybe your ObservableDictionary? Try creating that on the UI thread.

Comment: I try init variable freshFriends out of scope dispatcherTimer_tick event, in constructor of  VM. But problem is same. MyObservable dic is ok in my view, no dependency property or object in this class.